# SSH Tunnel proxy - view HTTPS Page

Tags: ssh, https, proxy, dns, tunnel

Really hope someone will answer to my question..

Basically got a **ssh tunnel** between MACHINE1 and MACHINE2, tunnel working as *proxy*, everything works well.

**test12** = *https server - 10.0.0.1 - same network as MACHINE1*

**MACHINE1** = *windows 7 x64 - 192.168.6.20 (the one running ssh server)*

**MACHINE2** = *windows 7 x64 - 192.168.2.8 (different network from MACHINE1)*

So when i use putty on MACHINE2 to connect via ssh to MACHINE1, I Can browse https and https sites and see MACHINE1 public ip!

But when i navigate to test12, it can't display page!

**PUTTY CONSOLE MACHINE2 - VIEW**

[image]

As you can see using iexplore and setting proxy, the page can not be displayed! Also tried to edit C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts to resolve test12 to 127.0.0.1 but have aniway error!

**DNS CHANGE MACHINE2 - VIEW**

[image]

Comment: Anyone know hot to solve this!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the problem!**

The IP of *test12* was actually different, it was *192.168.6.120*.

The problem was that socks proxy doesn't automatically resolves internal network dns names! so the solution was simply add to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts this line: **192.168.6.120 test12**